# change mat-tab to mat-step for using mat-horizontal-stepper

Tags: angular-material

I have working code of tabs set like this:

```
   <mat-tab-group  class="sm:px-2" #tabGroup [animationDuration]="'1'">
                            <mat-tab style="height:100%" label="{{sectionItem.sectionName}}"
                               *ngFor="let sectionItem of srDynamicFields; trackBy: trackByFn; ; let i = index">
                                style="overflow-y: auto;"> </mat-tab> </mat-tab-group>
```

the isuue I have I need to replace it for stepper `mat-horizontal-stepper` if I am changing mat-tab to mat-step its not woeking and the data not working well. how can I do it? thanks